# Get unique identifier for view in ExpandableList Android

Tags: java, android, dictionary, expandablelistview

I want to create an ArrayList or Map that holds the checked state of a childView. However in order to do this I need a unique identifier for each view.

I tried view.getId() but that returned -1 for every row in the list.
I tried childPosition but that gets repeated within every group.

Example:

- A1 = 0
- A2 = 1
- B1 = 0

The only thing I see is a combination of the groupPosition and the childPosition unless someone else knows of something else.  So is there a way to create a Map or ArrayList that contains an accessible index of two separate integers?

Or a way to combine childPosition and groupPosition to get one unique identifier that I can use for each childView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to combine both integers ?

```
String identifier = groupPosition + "-" + childPosition;
//which is the id of
HashMap<String, boolean> checkedElements = new HashMap<String, boolean>();
```

I'm afraid there is nothing magic.

Comment: My only problem with this is that I need to add the view's checked state (boolean) to an ArrayList or Map and have a way to access it again with a unique index that I can recreate with the given information.  If the identifier is a string I can't use that as an index in my Map or ArrayList.

Comment: I'm new, didn't realize that could be done with a HashMap.  Will see if that works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the static method `View.generateViewId();` like that:
`yourView.setId( View.generateViewId() );`

And put in the same time this id in your `ArrayList`.